# for the following class, how do you get the value of 42 x?

Tags: javascript, class, return, var

for the following class,  how do  you get the value of 42 x ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbJrF.png)

Comment: Please avoid using images to convey what is mainly / could easily conveyed through text.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

> The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

So the answer would be `x.Y`